# How can I create functions which access variables that are created in the run function of a subclassed python Process

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, scope

If I have a python class

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class A(Process):
    def run(self):
        self.var = "asdf"

    def pprint(self):
        print(self.var)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = A()
    foo.start()
    foo.pprint()
    bar = A()
    bar.pprint()
```

I get the traceback error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple.py", line 13, in <module>
    foo.pprint()
  File "simple.py", line 8, in pprint
    print(self.var)
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'var'
```

Can I access instance variables that are defined within the run function, with other functions defined in the scope of the class?

Answer (score 0):

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class A(Process):  
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.var = value  
  def run(self):
    self.var = "asdf"
  def pprint(self):
    print(self.var)


foo = A("asdf")
foo.start()
foo.pprint()
bar = A("qwerty")
bar.pprint()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `run()` function is executed in another process and the variable is only created there while `pprint()` is executed in current process. You can e.g. use a `Manager` to get a `dict` to store data common for all processes or exchange data using pipes or queues (read the documentation about that).

Comment: Would I use a queue to call functions from within that external process?

Comment: @user1876508 Queues are mainly for transferring data. You can create a custom `Manager` and register a class for calls across processes. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#customized-managers